# Making an Indexer In Android

Tags: java, android

I want to create a search application in android something like [AndroSearch](http://www.guidingtech.com/49107/android-search-better-androsearch/). For the same, I think I want to index the *Contacts, App Details, SMS* etc. What is the best way to make this indexer? Using *SQLite* will work or not ?

I am thinking of implementing this indexer as multiple modules, like a module for Contacts, One for SMS, like that. So that I can parallelly access those modules and within a short time can get multiple results related to one search query. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Using SQLite will work or not ?

You need to use the Content Provider for this which internally uses the SQLite.

> I am thinking of implementing this indexer as multiple modules, like a
>   module for Contacts, One for SMS, like that. So that I can parallelly
>   access those modules and within a short time can get multiple results
>   related to one search query. How to do this?

For this you can refer this app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sveltoz.smartsearch&hl=en

Comment: >>You need to use the Content Provider for this which internally uses the SQLite.<< Yes. Understood. Is there any better way other than using Content Provider all the time ? Like keeping a local copy in some better way that SQLite ?

Comment: If you use content provider then you will get the updated data of Android system as well as as the storage space will get saved. If you use local copy then you have to check for updated data always because when user will add some data that data will be inserted in android system data and not your sqlite database..